# Hide part of moving container

Tags: mask, createjs, easeljs

How do I hide that part of a moving container with `Pic2` inside so that it doesn't overlap the container with `Pic1`? There is a splitter (in white) and it should visually split those moving pictures.

Here is an exmaple: http://cjstest.blg.lt/test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `mask` property to apply a shape as a clipping path on any DisplayObject.

I ported your example to JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/t8dzrunj/

It is important to note that an object's mask is automatically moved to draw at the coordinates of the clip. This means that I had to change the sample so that the `rightBG` is what is moving (instead of its Container), and then mask the container. Since the container is moved on the x, I had to massage the coordinates of the mask a little, but I got it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/t8dzrunj/1/

Here is the code to create and apply the mask:

```
var mask = new createjs.Shape();
mask.graphics.f("#f00").dr(40,0,260,480);
rightSubCont.mask = mask;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's definitely what I was looking for. Thank you, Lanny.